# rnd function in ms access returns same value

Tags: ms-access

I have the following ms access query:

`SELECT * from mytable WHERE chaptId IN (SELECT Top 1 chaptId  FROM  (SELECT chaptId, Rnd(RowID) AS RandomValue FROM mytable) ORDER  BY RandomValue)`

Basically it takes from a table a random unique chaptID value, and for this value extracts all the rows that have this chaptID value.

it works perfectly through ms access. When I try to run it from within VB6 (ADO DB), it always returns the same chaptID and thus the same chapter. Searching I found that I have to use the Randomize function. I don't know how to include it in the query. So I tried to wrap it like this: `Rnd(Randomize(RowID))`. I did not know how else to use it.

The message I get is `Undefined function Randomize in epxression`

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, as discovered, to randomize when using `Rnd` using ODBC/ADO.

This means we have to introduce randomness somehow.

An obvious choice is by using the system timer:

```
SELECT * from mytable WHERE chaptId IN (SELECT Top 1 chaptId  FROM  (SELECT chaptId, Rnd(-1 * (RowID + Timer() * 100)) AS RandomValue FROM mytable) ORDER  BY RandomValue)
```

Comment: @MirrorMirror Try the edit, forgot that you need to multiply by -1 to seed. Note that if you rely on the timer to randomize, you do need to wait a tiny bit to get a different result.

Answer (score 1):

You may study my project on *rownumbers*, [VBA.RowNumbers](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers), which also deals with pseudo-random ordering - see paragraph 4 and the form `Form_RandomProducts.cls``.

For truly random numbers, see my project [VBA.Random](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Random). A little more code, but simple to implement.

If you only can run native Access SQL, this basic query should do (as your subquery):

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    Rnd(-Timer()*[RowID]) AS [Rnd Generator]
FROM
    mytable
ORDER BY
    Rnd(-Timer()*[RowID]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is to get a random chapter each time, why not get a random chapter before running the query:

```
Dim FirstChapter as Integer
Dim LastChapter as Integer
Dim RandomChapter as Integer

FirstChapter = DMin("ChaptId","mytable")
LastChapter = DMax("ChaptId","mytable")

Randomize 
 
RandomChapter = Int((LastChapter - FirstChapter + 1) * Rnd + FirstChapter)

'run vba ADO code for the following SQL
"SELECT * from mytable WHERE chaptId IN (" & RandomChapter & ")"
```